# batch process files in subfolder instead of current folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I seem to have a problem using either `%cd%` or `%~dp0` in a file path in a batch file, which I think is because the file path has a space in it.

The files are in the path `C:\Users\maxmik\Desktop\WEM CONVERTER`. I am using ww2ogg and revorb to convert wem files into ogg, but want to be able to use a subfolder I named `wemfiles` to hold the wem files and converted ogg files, instead of having them all in the same folder as the batch file and executables.

Here's the batch file script:

```
@echo off

for %%f in (%~dp0/wemfiles/*.wem) do ww2ogg.exe %%f --pcb packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin
for %%f in (%~dp0/wemfiles/*.ogg) do revorb.exe %%f

echo Job Complete!
pause
pause
```

here's the output from it:

```
Audiokinetic Wwise RIFF/RIFX Vorbis to Ogg Vorbis converter 0.24 by hcs

Input: C:\Users\mmaksim\Desktop\WEM
Error opening C:\Users\mmaksim\Desktop\WEM
Could not open input file.
Job Complete
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If I use the following batch file instead with the wem files in the same folder as the executables, it works just fine.

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.wem) do ww2ogg.exe %%f --pcb packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin
for %%f in (*.ogg) do revorb.exe %%f

echo Job Complete!
pause
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doublequotes are your friend:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("%~dp0wemfiles\*.wem") Do ww2ogg.exe --pcb packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin "%%A"
For %%A In ("%~dp0wemfiles\*.ogg") Do revorb.exe "%%A" 
Echo Job Complete!
Pause
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly. By the way, is there some reason you used %%A instead of %%f? And are the doublequotes only needed in a batch file if the files being operated on aren't in the current/working directory?

Comment: The same reason why I don't slice a loaf of bread from the middle. My best advice is to use doublequotes all of the time, they help to keep strings linked and protect problematic characters.

Comment: Okay haha. I hear ya. I guess the %%n is just assigning a variable in a for loop, and the letter isn't important. I suppose if I hadn't copied the batch file from a wiki and written it from scratch to begin with, I would've used %%A as well. Thanks!